# Sonar API call with Groovy script, Disabling anonymous Authentication in SonarQube

Tags: groovy, sonarqube

How to pass authentication information to access SonarQube API from groovy script by disabling user authentication in SonarQube ?

Im already consuming the SonarQube API with the default setting(user authentication disabled.) using Groovy script.

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous authentication"? That seems like an oxymoron.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam - Anonymous user browse. let me edit the question to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't *really* want to disable authentication, you just want to be able to run your analysis:

1. Create a technical user that you'll use only for running analyses. We'll call him "Techie"
2. Grant Techie permissions to [Execute Analysis](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions), either on the project in question or at the global level. Since we're only using Techie to execute analyses, this should be the only permission he needs
3. Generate a [user token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) for Techie's account
4. Pass Techie's token as the value of `sonar.login`, and omit `sonar.password`
5. Analyze away!